# Windows não encontra variáveis do ambiente do R executando shinys por arquivos .bat(lote) ou shell

Tags: r, windows, shell

Tenho um Shiny salvo na rede que disponibilizo para usuários através de atalhos que executam o shiny por shell no Windows (o atalho é um arquivo .bat no desktop to usuário)

Tenho algumas senhas de acesso nesse shiny que salvei como variáveis de ambiente, e ao executar o shiny com essas credenciais no windows pelo shell, ele não encontra as variáveis de ambiente.

Há algum modo do windows achar as variáveis de ambiente salvas no R através do `usethis::edit_r_environment` ?

A ideia seria executar o shiny sem precisar deixar todas as credenciais no script, por motivos de segurança.

Comment: As variáveis que você criou só são vistas no computador onde você as criou. Se os usuários acessam esse "shiny" por meio de um um bat através da rede eles não vêem essas variáveis.

Comment: mas mesmo no meu computador, onde criei o shiny e salvei as variáveis, ao usar o .bat, o windows não acha as variáveis

Comment: Como você criou as variáveis?

Comment: criei com `usethis::edit_r_environ()`